# How to retrieve Custom values to Image metadata in swift 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Am creating an application for image share related things. Here my requirement is **I have to store some custom information(Name, PhoneNumber, Price) into the Image Metadata and retrieve it back**.

I use UIImagePickerController to capture the image and set my information into the image metadata in UIImagePickerControllerDelegate like below mentioned:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let profileImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    let imageData: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage!, 1)!
    let cgImgSource: CGImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil)!
    let uti: CFString = CGImageSourceGetType(cgImgSource)!
    let dataWithExif: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(data: imageData)
    let destination: CGImageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((dataWithExif as CFMutableData), uti, 1, nil)!
    let imageProoperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(cgImgSource, 0, nil)! as NSDictionary
    let mutable: NSMutableDictionary = imageProoperties.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary

    let EXIFDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = (mutable[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String] as? NSMutableDictionary)!
    print("Before Modification: \(EXIFDictionary)")
    EXIFDictionary[kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment as String] = "\(self.m_NameTxtFd.text!):\(self.m_PhoneNumberTxtFd.text!):\(self.m_PriceTxtFd.text!)"
    mutable[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String] = EXIFDictionary

    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, cgImgSource, 0, (mutable as CFDictionary))
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)

    let testImage: CIImage = CIImage(data: dataWithExif as Data, options: nil)!
    let newProperties: NSDictionary = testImage.properties as NSDictionary
    print("After Modification : \(newProperties)") //Here I Got My Information is Stored Successfully

    self.m_ImgView.image = self.convert(cmage: testImage)
    self.saveImageDocumentDirectory()
}

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Now am going to save the image in NSDocumentDirectory like below mentioned:

```
func saveImageDocumentDirectory(){
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("apple.jpg")
        let image = self.m_ImgView.image
        print(paths)
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
    }
```

Now am going to fetch the stored image in another view controller like below mentioned:

```
func getImage(){
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let imagePAth = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("apple.jpg")
        print(imagePAth)
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePAth){
            self.m_ImgView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePAth)
            self.fetchImageDetails()
        }else{
            print("No Image")
        }
    }
```

I successfully got the image and now I have to fetch the information from image metadata like below mentioned:

```
func fetchImageDetails() {
        let profileImage = self.m_ImgView.image!
        let ciImage: CIImage = CIImage(cgImage: profileImage.cgImage!)
        let newProperties: NSDictionary = ciImage.properties as NSDictionary
    }
```

But issue is the information is null in image property.

Please guide me to retrieve the custom information from stored Image.

Comment: `kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary` is not a `String`. Try this `metadata?[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] as? NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: @Kamran - Thanks for your quick response. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @Kamran - Getting same crash kamran. At this line in ImagePickerControllerDelegate method `let metaStr: NSDictionary = ["Name": self.m_NameTxtFd.text!, "Phone": self.m_PhoneNumberTxtFd.text!, "Price": self.m_PriceTxtFd.text!]
        exifData?.setValue(metaStr, forKey: kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String)` crash is `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

Comment: On this line `let metaStr: String = "\(self.m_NameTxtFd.text!),\(self.m_PhoneNumberTxtFd.text!),\(self.m_PriceTxtFd.text!)"` there is a possibility that any/all of your `textField` text is `nil`.

Comment: To set or get the value for any dictionary key that has `Exif` use the above approach.

Comment: Am using KCGImagePropertyExifDictionary. And metaStr as all values("Sabs,1234567890,12$")

Comment: @Kamran - Hi Kamran, finally I stored the information. But can't retrieve back the info from Image. FYI: I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

First create NSMutableDictionary and set value to NSMutableDictionary when you set value to then you don't need to set again to metadata you directly assign to NSMutableDictionary to Metada.

```
    let metadata = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] as? NSMutableDictionary                
    let exifData = NSMutableDictionary()            
    let metaStr = "\(self.m_NameTxtFd.text!),\(self.m_PhoneNumberTxtFd.text!),\(self.m_PriceTxtFd.text!)"
    exifData.setValue(metaStr, forKey: kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String)                       
    metadata = exifData
```

Comment: Did you try this code. It will again take him to the same crash he already fixed. Can you explain what exactly you fixed in above code?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it is not crash. You just have to set values to NSMutableDictionary and assign to metadata and you don't need to set values from metadata.

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav - Thanks for your response. Finally I stored the information. But can't retrieve back the info from Image. FYI: I updated the question.

Comment: @Sabs Can you please upward for answer which is storing information in image.

Comment: sorry @AbhishekJadhav I can't understand what you are telling

Answer (score 0):

```
fileManager.requestImageData(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (imagedata, dataUTI, orientation, info ) in

 if let info = info {

if info.keys.contains(NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey")) {

 path = info[NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey")] as? NSURL

 size = (imagedata! as NSData).length

self.name = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for:fetchResult.object(at: i)).first?.originalFilename
 self.imageData = imagedata

           }
       }
   })
```